# Installing Ubuntu on HP Envy 4 - 1104tx (preinstalled Windows 8)

Tags: windows, bootloader, uefi

I have been using Linux for more than 2 years now. I had hp pavilion dv4 laptop and Ubuntu 12.04 was working great. I recently purchased HP Envy 4 - 1104tx which has Windows 8 preinstalled. I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 but since it is not much compatible with UFEI, I downloaded 64 bit iso of ubuntu 12.10. Made a liveUSB using UnetBootin 583. I followed [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) but still I am not able to boot with LiveUSB. I disabled secure boot. There is no option for fast boot or anything as such. It still wouldn't work. I also tried booting through Legacy, but I'm unable to install via LiveUSB. Is there any other way? I don't have SSD so no problem of fake raid.

Is there some way by which I can install Ubuntu (12.04 preferred)? I don't care about Windows 8. Is there any way via which I can install Ubutnu over Windows 8? (I don't have a CD/DVD ROM).

Comment: `I also tried booting through Legacy, but I'm unable to install via LiveUSB.` Where are you facing the error? Did you got grub prompt?

Comment: No. Even after changing the boot order, Windows 8 loads.

Comment: Turns out there was some problem with the bootloader. Made a LiveUSB of 12.04 with proper bootloader. Turned secure boot off. Installed. Working fine.

Comment: How do I close this question?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a Lenovo. Load Ubuntu onto a USB stick and then in Windows try running it from there. It will give you the option of when you want to restart the machine. Tell it to restart straight away and it should allow you to boot the USB.

*Note*: you may still need to press <kbd>F9</kbd> or it may prompt you to press something else.